# jQuery Remove Last Added Row

Tags: jquery

I have a form that allows users to add new rows with this code:

```
 var insertRow = function() {

$(".box")
    .append($("<div class='row' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-3'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name[]' placeholder='Item Name'></input></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-4'><textarea class='form-control' name='description[]' placeholder='Description' rows='1'></textarea></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>$</span><input type='text' class='form-control' name='price[]' onKeyUp='calculate()' placeholder='Unit Price'></input></div></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-1'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity[]' onKeyUp = 'calculate()' placeholder='Qty'></input></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='input-group'><span      class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>$</span><input type='text' placeholder='Line total' class='form-control' name='total[]' readonly></input></div></div>"))
    .append($("</div><a href='#' class='remove_row'>remove</a>")); 

}
```

I am trying to use this code to remove but it is not working:

```
 // Remove parent of 'remove' link when link is clicked.
 $('.box').on('click', '.remove_row', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();

$(this).parent().remove();
 });
```

What this does is remove all rows, not just the last one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All your added tags don't belong to a "row", it is just a bunch of tags inserted one after the other. The remove code will remove all the "rows" in this example.

Try something like this:

```
var insertRow = function() {

var row = $("<div>")
    .append($("<div class='row' style='padding-bottom:10px;'>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-3'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='name[]' placeholder='Item Name'></input></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-4'><textarea class='form-control' name='description[]' placeholder='Description' rows='1'></textarea></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='input-group'><span class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>$</span><input type='text'     class='form-control' name='price[]' onKeyUp='calculate()' placeholder='Unit Price'></input></div></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-1'><input type='text' class='form-control' name='quantity[]' onKeyUp = 'calculate()' placeholder='Qty'></input></div>"))
    .append($("<div class='col-lg-2'><div class='input-group'><span      class='input-group-addon' id='basic-addon1'>$</span><input type='text' placeholder='Line total' class='form-control' name='total[]' readonly></input></div></div>"))
    .append($("</div><a href='#' class='remove_row'>remove</a>")); 
    $(".box").append(row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because `this` is the `a.remove_row` that actually is sibling of the div that you want to remove, you need to use siblings("div.row") or prev() for remove.